# How to hide previous signers' signatures in DocuSign when using the API for multiple signers?

Tags: docusignapi

I am using the DocuSign API to send a document to multiple signers in a sequential order. I want to ensure that each signer can only see their own signature and not the signatures of previous signers. Currently, the default behavior allows each recipient to see the document and any signatures placed on it before their turn in the routing order.

I have tried using the documentVisibility property with "visible": "recipient" for each signer, but it doesn't seem to achieve the desired result.

Is there a way to completely hide the signatures of previous signers from subsequent signers in DocuSign using the API? If not, are there any alternative approaches or workarounds to achieve this?

Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The only possible situation where you can do this with DocuSign today AFAIK is when the recipients have their signature elements (tabs) on different documents.

So, if you have 2 recipients and you have 2 pages (you can separate a 2 page doc into 2 documents of 1 page each) and you places on the first page only signing element(s) for the first signer and on the second page only signing elements for the second signer - then you can do this using DocuSign Document Visibility feature.

The above is true if it's via the API or not via the API.

The reason for this is that when a signer signs a document there's a requirement that they see exactly what they sign, you cannot ask to sign something and hide some of the information in it. The signature of prior signers becomes part of the document when they finish signing so what you're asking is not possible if all these tabs are on the same page (document).

Comment: Is it possible to send individual copies of a singular document to distinct signers?

Comment: Sure, use a different envelope for each signer.

Comment: Correct, you can even use a feature called "Bulk Send" that makes it easy to send a large number of envelopes to many people.